# How to manage multiple projects in single wrokspace?

Tags: ros, catkin, build-package, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How to manage multiple projects in a single catkin workspace?? Like if I have a project named project_1 then some packages in it and then another project named project_2 then some packages in it. Like tree given below.

```
catkin_ws/
  src/
    CMakeLists.txt
    project_1
      package_1/
        CMakeLists.txt
        package.xml
        ...
      package_n/
        CMakeLists.txt
        package.xml
    project_2
      package_1/
        CMakeLists.txt
        package.xml
        ...
      package_n/
        CMakeLists.txt
        package.xml
  build/
  devel/
  logs/
```

**If we can make a structure like this, then how to build this?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394641/how-to-manage-multiple-projects-in-single-wrokspace?/) by [jay-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/94188/jay-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to use `catkin tools` to manage multiple packages in one workspace. To install `catkin tools` run, `sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin python-catkin-tools`

Quick example is, you can build specific package in your `catkin_ws` using `catkin build <package-name>` and you can clean the workspace with `catkin clean` to clean the workspace before building other package. It doesn't matter in which sub folder the package is inside the `src/`. You can also use `Tab` key for auto-completion of package name.

You can refer [this](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet.html) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2022-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jay-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/94188/jay-b/) on 2022-01-20**:
I also use catkin tools to manage multiple packages in my workspace. But my situation was like I have some packages in `src/` folder, then build them after that I tried to put them in a subfolder inside the `src/`. That's an error right. So I got it like make a subfolder inside `src/`, and then create package inside that subfolder, after then build.
So thanks.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-01-21**:
You can not have same package name twice in one workspace. You can create another workspace if you are doing this to keep backup of the code.

**Comment by [jay-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/94188/jay-b/) on 2022-01-22**:
Yes, you are right.